# Break One Long Text into Two Lines

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="posted_wrap">
    <div id="posted_middle">
        <div id="posted_top"></div>
        <div id="textcontent">
            <br /><p>ARTICLE</p>
        </div>
        <br />
             <div id="posted_bottom"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The above div product the following UI:

[image]

The long text you see represents the article.

**Problem 1:** I need to let this long text moves automatically into the new line. Example:

[image]

**Problem 2:** How can i set a specific fixed minimum height e.g. 300px , so if a user enters few lines, the article box doesn't look too short.

CSS Details - This is my first project, not familiar with web-design:
    posted_wrap {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0px;
        margin-right: 55px;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }

```
textcontent {   
    margin-right: 25px;
}

    textcontent p { 
             margin:0 auto;
             text-align:center;
             width: 663px;
    }

posted_top {
    width:688px;
    height: 9px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background: url(images/postedcontent_top.png) no-repeat center top;
}

posted_middle {
    width:688px;
    background: url(images/postedcontent_middle.png) repeat-y center center;
}

posted_bottom{
    width:688px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url(images/postedcontent_bottom.png) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

Comment: "*How can i set a specific fixed minimum height e.g. 300px*" - `min-height: 300px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a width:

```
textcontent p {
width:640px
}
```

and use `min-height` for problem 2

**EDIT:** Your words shouldn't be too looooooooooooooooooooooong. Generate [random texts](http://www.lipsum.com/) instead of a long `aaaaaaaaa`.

Answer (score 0):

If a div has a style that specifies a width, then the content within it will break automatically.  (This is assuming no overflow property has been set.)

For height, you want the min-height property.  But be sure to read [sitepoint's description](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-height)  of this; there are caveats and it is buggy in IE 6.

Comment: Setting the width does not cause the content to break into new line if the text is just one long word. This is actually a problem in many web forums. There are always some nasty people who like to enter long text without spaces to mesh the display. In such case, some server side script is needed to break too long words.